# Statistical analysis

Tags: software-recommendation

can any one offer advice please? I am going to need to do some statistical analysis soon. Looking for significant difference. I am a bit of a dunce in this area but I will have help. Can you suggest which software would be most appropriate - in the past I have used SPSS. All suggestions will be welcome - thank you.

Comment: Can you comment more on what type of statistical analysis you'll be doing?

Answer (score 8):

Look into R or JGR. Both are open source alternatives to SPSS

R- http://www.r-project.org/

JGR- http://rforge.net/JGR/ (GUI for R)

Comment: R-project is also in the Ubuntu repositories as far as I know, though it may have been removed. Nonetheless, it is easy to compile from what I understand. I did a little more invesitgating on the pros & cons between the r-project & PSPP. I ran into a forum that has a pretty good analysis. See the #5 post from an Ubuntu user who tried both (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=646485). I have never used this type of software but from what I can see, r-project has a nice GUI front-end that PSPP does not, allowing for more ease of use.

Comment: Your last comment doesn't really make much sense.  R in and of itself is just a command line driven interactive statistical programming language.  There isn't a definitive GUI.  PSPP on the other hand does have a GUI and does strive for the "ease of use" that R doesn't necessarily care about.  The learning curve is greater for R but it is a much more powerful environment.

Comment: Check out the website..that should clear it up. I'll quote the first line of the website for you and save you some time: " JGR (speak 'Jaguar') is a universal and unified Graphical User Interface for R (it actually abbreviates Java Gui for R)."

http://rforge.net/JGR/

Comment: And what I'm saying is that the JGR doesn't really add much "ease of use".  You still need to know how to use R to use JGR - it just adds something so that you don't necessarily need to run R from the console.  Whereas with PSPP you do at least get menu driven abilities.

Comment: I haven't used R nor JGR as I stated and my analysis was based from what I read, but thanks for clearing that up. It seemed, from the description in the forum post I provided as well as from the JGR website,  that it was a good alternative to PSPP and offered more ease of use for the seemingly popular R. If that's not the case, then fair enough.

Comment: It does make it easier to use R.  But you still need to know how to use R which isn't something is easy to learn initially.

Comment: RStudio is an incredibly useful tool for using R. See here: http://www.rstudio.org/

Answer (score 4):

[Libre Office - Calc](http://www.libreoffice.org/features/calc/) is one of the simpler options.  Calc provides a spreadsheet and it is essentially a replacement for Microsoft Excel.  It also provides a suite of statistical functions that once again depending on the sophistication you need could provide everything you need to perform an analysis. The [list of statistical functions](http://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Statistics_Functions) is quite extensive and you can check that out to see if it would contain what you need.

---

[PSPP](http://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/) has the goal of being an SPSS replacement.  If all you're looking to do is some simple analysis this will probably be good enough for you.  It doesn't completely replicate all of the features of SPSS but it is open source and is free to use.  Since you already have SPSS experience this would probably be the best program for you to go with.  I prefer R and I think it is much more powerful but it doesn't sound like you're going to be doing anything requiring too much sophistication and R does has a bigger learning curve to go along with it.

---

[R](http://cran.r-project.org/) is a great choice but it does have a significant learning curve.  If you're not comfortable programming some code yourself it would take a while to get used to.  With that said it is very powerful and there are a couple of tools that try to help make the experience easier.

[Rkward](http://rkward.sourceforge.net/) is a decent tool and that provides a GUI for R and some menu driven options to conduct your analysis (with the plus side of giving you the code used to actually conduct the analysis).

[Rstudio](http://rstudio.org/) is a nice IDE for R that provides some nice features.  It won't help you learn R but it will make using R quite a bit nicer.

There are other tools such as Rcmdr, JGR, Emacs+ESS, Eclipse+StatET for making using R either easier by providing a nice editor for writing your scripts or by providing a nice GUI interface.

If you want to go with R then initially you'll probably want to give something like Rkward a try and maybe eventually move to Rstudio.  If you think R is a route you might take you can leave a comment and I can definitely add to this section.  I use R all the time and it's my preferred tool for an analysis.

---

To summarize:

- R is very powerful and I can guarantee that it will be able to do what you need to do for a statistical analysis but it has a learning curve though and if you don't feel comfortable programming it probably isn't the tool for you.
- PSPP is an SPSS replacement and since you have prior experience it does seem to be a natural fit for your goals.
- Libre Office - Calc is probably simplest tool here but depending on the sophistication you need it will most likely get the job done and you won't even have to leave a spreadsheet environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are after something like SPSS in particular, you could try GNU PSPP, which is packaged in Ubuntu. It strives to remain compatible with the SPSS
command language and data formats, but does not support all SPSS
commands.

I am typing on a iphone so I can't give you the direct link. Just google it. The interface should be easy to navigate as it is to me the open source version of SPSS.

LINK: http://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/

Answer (score 0):

Try this link   http://www.sofastatistics.com/downloads.php

I already installed it on my Ubuntu 12.04 and its amazing.